# reindex a dataframe based on suffix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reindex

Assume we have a dataframe with 150 rows and 47 columns. The first 2 columns are always named 'name' and 'country'. The rest of the columns might have a different name but the suffices will always follow the same logic. The first 15 will be _a, the next 15 will be _b and last 15 will be _c.

```
df1  
name   country  col1 _a  col2_a   ...   col15_a   col1_b   col2_b  ...  col15_b  col1_c ...  col15_c  
...    ...      ...      ...      ...   ...       ...       ...    ...   ...      ...    ...   ...
```

I want to create a new dataframe that will have the following form

```
df1  
name   country   col1_a  col1_b  col1_c  col2_a  col2_b  col2_c ...    col15_a  col15_b  col15_c
...     ...      ...      ...  ...     ...      ...      ...    ...     ...      ...      ...
```

So basically I want the column name and country to be first and then the logic is
1st column with suffix_a, 1st column with suffix_b, 1st column with suffix_c,
2nd column with suffix_a, 2ndcolumn with suffix_b, 2ndcolumn with suffix_c,
etc until we reach
15th column with suffix_a, 15th column with suffix_b, 15th column with suffix_c,

In order to tackle this issue I created a subset with only columns with the suffices and tried to use he following function

```
def get_sort_key(label):
    label = str(label)
    match = re.search(r'(^\D+)(_.)$',label)
    if match:
        prefix = match.group(1)
        suffix = match.group(2)
        return prefix+suffix
    return ''
```

and from my main

```
scores = scores.sort_index(axis=1, kind='mergesort', key=lambda x: get_sort_key(x))
```

However I get the following error

```
ValueError: User-provided `key` function must not change the shape of the array.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the issue correctly, the 15 columns have the same names, with the difference that the have different suffixes that could be "_a", "_b" or "_c", so the function sort_index will automatically sort the columns as you desire.

To illustrate my point I have created a df using this code, similar to yours, but instead of 15 columns I have 5 of each suffix (Note: The values are completely random, as they are not relevant to the issue):

```
cols = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"]
suffix = ["_a", "_b", "_c"]

list_cols = []
for suf in suffix:
    for col in cols:
        list_cols.append(col+suf)

list_cols = ["name", "country"] + list_cols
data = [np.random.normal(size=17) for i in range(10)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=list_cols)
```

If I try to sort this df with the sort_index function I will get the same sort as the example that you provided, as you can see by doing:

```
df1.set_index(["name", "country"]).sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
```

Please let me know if this helps you or if I misunderstood the issue.